# Are these threads running in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
from threading import Thread
from threading import currentThread


def f(i, name="default"):
    print("Thread named {} with id={} is working".format(name, i))


for i in range(3):
    Thread(target=f, args=(i,), kwargs={"name": "%s" % currentThread().getName()}).start()
```

This is the result that I get:

```
>> Thread named MainThread with id=0 is working
>> Thread named MainThread with id=1 is working
>> Thread named MainThread with id=2 is working
```

if these three threads are running in parallel why they all have the same name, if they are not running in parallel how can I change my code to make them run in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the argument `kwargs={"name": "%s" % currentThread().getName()}` is evaluated at the same time as (or more precisely, just before) `Thread` is called. So each thread gets the keyword argument `name="MainThread"` passed to the function it is supposed to execute.

Try calling `currentThread()` inside `f`, for example:

```py
def f(i):
    print("Thread named {} with id={} is working".format(currentThread().getName(), i)
```

Answer (score 1):

> if these three threads are running in parallel why they all have the same name

This is because your `currentThread().getName()` is being called in the thread spawning them, so it is passing the name of that thread to all the spawned ones.

> if they are not running in parallel how can I change my code to make
>   them run in parallel?

They are running in separate threads, but due to the behaviour of CPython, they are running the Python bytecode on the same processor, thus not fully concurrently. In order to make them run on separate processors, use the [`Multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Comment: "They are running ... on the same processor" There is a grain of truth to this but it's misleading overall. You are presumbly thinking of the Python GIL, which stops multiple threads running Python code at the same time. But if multiple threads are running C code (e.g. you're using numpy to perform matrix operations) then they can run simultaneously on different processor cores. Python threads are also useful for blocking I/O (e.g. reading from a socket) because I/O functions release the GIL.

Comment: @ArthurTacca Thanks! I'll modify the answer.

Comment: Re, "... not fully concurrently." Two threads are concurrent if both are started before either one of them finishes. Threads can be "fully" concurrent even on a system that has just one processor. But, "due to the behavior of CPython" (i.e., due to the GIL), they can not perform _parallel computations_ on a multi-processor system.

Comment: @SolomonSlow As I already explained in my previous comment, they *can* perform parallel computations depending on what library you're using. Many computational libraries, such as numpy, release the GIL while doing CPU processing.

Comment: @ArthurTacca, Yes, that's true: The CPython GIL does not absolutely prevent parallel computation. But, the only point that I was trying to make was about the meaning of the word "concurrent." I only mentioned the GIL in order to illustrate the difference between "concurrent" and "parallel" computations.